# convert a 1D array (K,1) to a 2D consensus/agreement array (K,K) with 1's or 0's if values match

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

First array (K,1) is one dimensional with values for each indexed item

> (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) = [1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2] where A=1, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=1, F=3, G=1 and H=2.

We want to create a (K, K) array of consensus or agreement values that would be a

> (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) x (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) matrix.

So that if any two indexed items had the same value in the original one-dimensional array, then the new value will be 1, but if the two items had different values then the new value will be zero.

For example, because B=2 and H=2 in the original one-dimensional array, then B, H =1 for the 2-D consensus matrix array, but because of A=1 and B=2 in the original array, then A, B=0 in the consensus matrix.

A [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VewcE.jpg) to the beginning array and the desired result

Also, looking for a computationally efficient way because our K is typically 300 to 500 items, and possible values range from 1 to 7.

And we have to do the same process through 300 separate iterations or 300 different starting one-dimensional arrays (K,1) done one at a time to create 300 different consensus/agreement matrices.

I have not tried anything because I have no idea how to approach.

The expected result would be a `K x K` matrix with each cell either a 1 if the column and row item iD's originally had the same value, and a zero if they originally did not have the same values in the starting one-dimensional array (K,1).

> i.e,  (B =2, H=2) therefore (B,H=1)
>   but (A=1, B=2) therefore (A,B =0)

See also [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VewcE.jpg) to an image of the desired result from a sample input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you familiar with [numpy](https://www.numpy.org)? Are you willing for the result to be a numpy array rather than a basic Python list-of-lists?

Answer (score 1):

If our array is a numpy array, then we can take advantage of broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2])

np.equal(np.reshape(arr, (-1, 1)), arr)
```

The result is a `dtype('bool')` array, but that can be cast back to `int` if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks so much. We will try your great suggestion.

Comment: Kyle's solution worked like a charm. We ran Wards clustering on  K=300 samples, each with 118 gene expression features, then resampled 50 different times (i.e. randomly leave out 20% samples each time of cluster) and implemented his solution downstream of all 50 individual clustering outputs to give us 50 unique agreement matrices. The entire process start to finish took just 1.5 minutes!  BEAUTIFUL